# checking charsequence value is existing in arraylist of selected items in alertdialog

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-alertdialog

I have an charsequence using that i am creating an alert dialog with multichoice items option. How can check an array list contains the values of char sequence, if exist dont add that values otherwise add. Below is the way what i achieved but it always adding the already existing values. Please help how to avoid already existing values.

```
 String[] ratings = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}; 

 final ArrayList<String> ilist= new ArrayList();

 final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

 builder.setTitle("Select Ratings");
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(ratings, ratingschecked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                if(!ilist.contains((ratings[which]){
                    ilist.add(ratings[which]);
                   }
            } else if (ilist.contains(ratings[which])) {
                ilist.remove(ratings[which]);

                }
        }
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a `CharSequence[]` rather than a `String[]`? Given the number of calls to `String.valueOf` that you've got, it would make life a lot simpler to just have strings. Also note that you're using the raw `ArrayList` type rather than an `ArrayList<String>` - any reason for that? (I'd strongly encourage you to avoid raw types.)

Comment: I can't see **ilist** having any values.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I changed CharSequence[] to String[] and avoid raw Arraylist. How can i check the value of ratings already exist in ilist? This is need because i coming from child to this activity using OnBackPressed() so the selected values are adding more than 1 time. Please help.

Comment: @Clairvoyant - Hope i answered in above comment.

Comment: Why are you still calling `String.valueOf` all the time? Have you debugged into this to see what's in `ilist` when this code is executing? Also I note you're still using the raw type on the RHS of the assignment - I'd expect that to raise compiler warnings... You can also simplify your code by using a local variable for `ratings[which]` rather than evaluating it all over the place, and use `ratingschecked[which] = isChecked;` at the end. Oh, and you don't need to call `contains` before calling `remove` - just call `remove` unconditionally, and if the item doesn't exist, it'll just do nothing.